# Can I override as_json method for all models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to override `as_json` for all my models because I want to add a boolean value.

Model: `user.rb`

```
def as_json
  super.merge(date: DateTime.current)
end
```

Model: `book.rb`

```
def as_json
  super.merge(date: DateTime.current)
end
```

Then I'm trying to **override `as_json` method in concern** but it's not working.

Can I override as_json method shared for all my models?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Override it in your `ApplicationRecord`. All models should subclass `ApplicationRecord`, not `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Use a string key to be consistent. And consider how you want to handle collisions. You'll also want to handle collisions with existing keys, silently overwriting them probably isn't a good idea.

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def as_json
    super.merge("date" => DateTime.current) { |key, oldval, newval|
      raise "#{self} has existing #{key} => #{oldval.inspect}"
    }
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, @schwern answer is perfect for Rails versions >= 5.

Another way to do this is, by moving your method into a module and include that module in all your required models.

This works with older versions of Rails as well and gives the flexibility of selecting including of your feature.

```
require 'active_support/concern'
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def as_json
    super.merge(date: DateTime.current)
  end

  class_methods do
    ...
  end
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  include MyModule
  ...
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  include MyModule
  ...
end
```

Comment: There is no reason for the whole `ActiveSupport::Concern` here. Simply `module MyModule; def as_json; super.merge(date: DateTime.current); end ;end` would be enough.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Yeah, agree in this particular case. But, to add any further functionality there, it would help. If there's nothing else, they can remove ActiveSupport::Concern and its references.

Comment: Even if so, I don't understand why you defined `as_json` in the `included` block. By doing that the method will defined on the class, removing the possibility override the module method from the class (since it will be redefined instead). You could leave in `ActiveSupport::Concern` for future usage, but the method definition should not be in the `included` block, but in the normal module context instead.